# Is there a way to call the <div> id in setTimeOutFunction <script> call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***Functionality:***
Have set a game page whereby, the user is to scroll as quickly as possible to advance to the next page for a given time.But before, the game starts, there will be a slider fade-in countdown counter to notify user that the game will start in 3 secs.

Meanwhile, when the notification counter is notifying the user, none of the game block is suppose to show.Each individual game will only be displayed for interaction after the fade-in countdown counter is completed.

***What has been done:***

Initial `<div>` block:

```
 <div id="page2" class="img-wrapper" align= "center" style=" position: relative; background-image: url(Image/Page2.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; width: 100%;height: 100%;">

        <!--set id = content for  creation of fadein countdown counter-->
        <div id='content' style="opacity:1"></div>

        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
        </canvas>
        <canvas id="Counter" width="300" height="300">
        </canvas>

        <div id="UserInteraction" style="display:none" z-index="2">
            <img id="roller" style="position: relative; top:1100px; width: 100%" src="Image/rolling_pin/Rolling Pin Spin000.png"/>
            <img id="scroll" style="position:absolute; top: 1250px; left: 380px; overflow-y: auto;" src="Image/Scroll.png" >
        </div>
```

Javascript for the fade-in counter:

```
var count = 3;
        function updateTimer(){
            if(count > 0){
                $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $("#content").text(count);
                    $("#content").fadeIn();
                    count--;
                });

            }
            else if(count == 0){
                $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $("#content").text("Start!!");
                    $("#content").fadeIn();
                    count--;
                    /*To display the canvas and countDown() function in 2 sec interval
                    after the fadein countdown is completed
                    */
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        canvasFunction();
                        //HOW TO CALL <DIV id=USERINTERACTION>here
                        countDown();   
                    }, 2000)   
                });
                $("#content").fadeOut();
            }
            else {
                $("#content").fadeOut();
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
        setInterval(function(){updateTimer()},2000);
```

***ISSUE:***

I have managed to call the function of "canvasFunciton()" & "countDown" after the fade-in counter is completed. However, I am unsure of how to call the id = UserInteraction so that the 2 img tag will be displayed after the fade in counter. Could anyone please help?

Comment: _"//HOW TO CALL <DIV id=USERINTERACTION>here"_ ... I don't know what you mean by _"call"_ the div... but what's wrong with something like `$("#UserInteraction").show()` or .fadeIn() etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling in following way;

```
$("#UserInteraction").show();
```

I think it should work and will display that image.